# android - Uncaught exception from Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to use YoutubeAndroidPlayerAPI for my Cordova application. I have successfully built the project and I am able to pass data from Javascript to Java, and also am able to display a `Toast`, but I am not able to start the Youtube's activity.

My code which is getting the exception:

```
private void openVideo(final String videoid) {
    Intent youtubeIntent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) this.cordova, "myapikey", videoid);
    this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, youtubeIntent, 0);
}
```

From the logcat:

```
E/PluginManager(14974): Uncaught exception from plugin
E/PluginManager(14974): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity$1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
E/PluginManager(14974):         at YoutubePlugin.openVideo(YoutubePlugin.java:44)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at YoutubePlugin.execute(YoutubePlugin.java:30)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:95)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:130)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.promptOnJsPrompt(CordovaBridge.java:135)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient.onJsPrompt(SystemWebChromeClient.java:119)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:580)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
E/PluginManager(14974):         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/SystemWebChromeClient(14974): : Line -1470026189 : org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity$1
I/Web Console(14974): org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity$1 at :-1470026189
```

Comment: It cannot cast the CordovaInterface as an activity... I am looking at this based on an old plugin I wrote, so this might have changed... Try `this.cordova.getActivity()`

Comment: It didn't accept the current parameters, so I added none. And I cannot see any exceptions now. But it is not working either. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supplementing the right arguments to the method. Also I don't believe cordova has startActivityForResult method.

Try the following though.

```
private void openVideo(final String videoid) {
    Context mcontext=this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    Intent youtubeIntent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this.cordova.getActivity(), "myapikey", videoid);
    youtubeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mcontext.startActivity(youtubeIntent);
}
```

Comment: Alright it worked. Had been stuck for days and this solved my problem.